# Table Layout and Button click event

Tags: android, android-button, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

This is my xml table layout file:

```
ID  Car No  Timein      Timeout     Charge    Print

1   AA-123  9:00        12:00       1000      btnprint

2   BB-123  10:00       1:00        1000      btnprint

3   CC-123  10:00       1:00        1000      btnprint
```

On a print button click I want to get the row data and send it role by role to another activity.

How to get the table row values and button click parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `TextViews`(I think `Car No`, `TimeIn` etc are all `TextViews`, right?)  and the print `Button` are wrapped by a `TableRow` then it's pretty simple to get the data:

```
    printBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();
            TextView carNumber = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.the_id_ofTheCarNumberTextView);
                            String carNumberText = carNumber.getText().toString();   
            TextView timeIn = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.the_id_ofTheTimeInTextView);
                            String timeInText = carNumber.getText().toString();
            TextView timeOut = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.the_id_ofTheTimeOutTextView);
                            String timeOutText = carNumber.getText().toString();
            // etc get the rest of the fields
            // put the data in the intent and start send it to the new
            // activity
        }
    });
```

Depending on the number of rows, you may want to look at the `ListView` widget.